# Cannot find the source of a nullPointerException

Tags: java, user-interface

I am trying to make a simple GUI, but am running into some errors. I want to create 3 simple buttons, and have them display side by side, the length of the screen. How would I go about doing this ?

My code so far is :

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame ("JFrame");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel( );
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JButton buttons[] = new JButton[2];
    for(int i = 0;i<=buttons.length ; i++){
     panel.add(buttons[i]);
    }
    frame.getContentPane( ).add( panel );
    frame.setSize( 500, 500);
    frame.setVisible( true );
  }
```

Comment: what do you see when you step through the code in a debugger?

Comment: This isn't the source of your problem, but your for loop should be `for(int i = 0;i < buttons.length ; i++)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hm, if I recall, arrays of objects in Java are initialized with null references. So, in your for, you're adding null to the panel.

You would have to do this:

```
JButton buttons[] = new JButton[2];
for(int i = 0;i < buttons.length ; i++){
    buttons[i] = new JButton(/* whatever */);
    panel.add(buttons[i]);
}
```

Then again, this raises a question: why use an array of buttons if you can just add them as you create them?

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize the buttons in the array first.  You can do that like in the following example.

```
JButton buttons[] = new JButton[2];
for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
    buttons[i] = new JButton("" + i);
}
for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
    panel.add(buttons[i]);
}
```

The problem is that all of your buttons get initialized to `null` initially.  And components don't let you add `null` to them.

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize your buttons before adding them to the panel.

```
for(int i = 0;i<buttons.length ; i++){
    buttons[i] = new JButton();
    panel.add(buttons[i]);
}
```

Also, take note of the modification I made to the for loop `i < buttons.length` instead of `i <= buttons.length`

Here is a nice little example using various JButtons ([here](http://www.beginner-java-tutorial.com/jbutton.html)). It includes adding ImageIcons to the buttons as well. i.e. An error button.

```
URL imgURL = JButtonDemo.class.getResource("Error.jpg");
ImageIcon icon = new createImageIcon(imgURL ); // should check that imgURL is not null
buttons[0] = new JButton("Error!",icon);
```

This makes them a bit more useful than a default `JButton`